# Select and manipulate SQL data, DISTINCT and SUM?

Tags: sql, sorting, sum, distinct, summarization

Im trying to make a small report for myself to see how my much time I get inputed in my system every day.

The goal is to have my SQL to sum up the name, Total time worked and Total NG product found for one specific day.

In this order:

1.) Sort out my data for a specific 'date'. I.E 2016-06-03

2.) Present a DISTINCT value for 'operators'

3.) SUM() all time registered at this 'date' and by this 'operator' under 'total_working_time_h'

4.) SUM() all no_of_defects registered at this 'date' and by this 'operator' under 'no_of_defects'

date,        operator,      total_working_time_h,        no_of_defects

Currently I get the data I want by using the Query below. But now I need both the DISTINCT value of the operator and the SUM of the information. Can I use sub-queries for this or should it be done by a loop? Any other hints where I can learn more about how to solve this?

If i run the DISTINCT function I don't get the opportunity to sum my data the way I try.

```
    SELECT date,    operator,   total_working_time_h,   no_of_defects FROM {$table_work_hours} WHERE date = '2016-06-03' "
```

[image: Example of data as picture]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing the table structure or contents, the following query is only a good guess. The bits to notice and work with are `sum()` and `GROUP BY`. Actually syntax will vary a bit depending on what RDBMS you are using.

```
SELECT
   date
  ,operator
  ,SUM(total_working_time_h)  AS total_working_time_h
  ,SUM(no_of_defects)         AS no_of_defects
 FROM {$table_work_hours}
 WHERE date = '2016-06-03'
 GROUP BY
   date
  ,operator
```

(Take out the `WHERE` clause or replace it with a range of dates to get results per operator per date.)

Comment: You got my structure completely, did not even have to adjust the code. 

This one looks like it solved my problem fully. Thanks a lot. Will try to understand why I don't need the DISTINCT thou. I don't really follow how we make sure it sorts out only the information connected to the operator still.

Comment: Read a few articles on the whats, whys, and how to uses of the `group by` clause of the `select` statement. It's a long and involved subject, and incredibly useful.

Comment: I will, any suggestion on a quality place to read on at a beginner level?
Ofc I can google but there is always better to get some directions on sources since I don't really have the skills to decide whats good and not in this area.

Comment: SQLServerCentral has a number of good series of articles, including "Stairway to T-SQL DML". The seventh in the series discusses GROUP BY: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Stairway+Series/75779/

Comment: Thanks a lot for the link.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you are trying to do DISTINCT. You want to know the data, no of hours, etc for a specific date.

do this....

```
Select Date, Operator, 'SumWorkHrs'=sum(total_working_time_h),
  'SumDefects'=sum(no_ofDefects) from {$table_work_hours} 
       Where date='2016-06-03'
```

Comment: Will try this now but it looks like it will display the whole SUM as one amount. 

Was trying to attach some example data but could not format it as a table here. It just became a wall of text.

I want the data to be like "date" (one selected date), "operator" (one operator that worked during this specific day, only presented once.) , "SumOfHours" (The sum of all the hours logged on that name during that day.), "SumDefects" (The sum of all defects loged by the same operator during the same date).

Comment: Give you 1 for giving me heads up for other things I need to solve by using similar code as you just presented.

Comment: @JohannesLöfgren DISTINCT removes duplicates. I don't think you need it in this case. I don't do a lot of SQL but I only rarely use it.

Comment: I know that is removes duplicates. So in my may DISTINCT would also remove my data? Is that correct? I thought I could use to to avoid double data of in my case the name but still get the data from that line.

Comment: Well it's difficult to say because I don't see your data - but like i said, there are only certain cases where you'd use it. I don't think your data set is right for Distinct.

Comment: Check this out to give you a better idea....http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_distinct.asp

Comment: Thanks for the link. I added some rows of my data (as picture) in the question some days ago to help others in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(total_working_time) as total_working_time, 
SUM(no_of_defects) as no_of_defects , 
DISTINCT(operator) AS operator FROM {$table_work_hours} WHERE
date = '2016-06-03'
```

Comment: And if this doesnt work you will have to do some inner joins/left joins on the same table

Comment: I did not work. And I did not spend any time to manipulate the line since i got it working above. Thanks anyway!